# Facing issue converting C structure to C# structure while accessing unmanaged C/C++ dll function

Tags: c#

How can I convert a **C** struct  to a C# struct to send it as parameter to unmanaged dll function using interopservices.

**C** Structure

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned int opt,
   NDVAL val,
   byte type
} NDGETVAL; 

typedef union    
{    
int i,    
bool b,    
float f,    
char *t,    
} NDVAL
```

Comment: Fixed by changing

Answer (score 0):

```
  Converted c stracture to c#


      [StructLayout( LayoutKind.Explicit )]
       struct NDVAL
     {
       [FieldOffset( 0 )]
       int i;
       [FieldOffset( 0 )]
       bool b;
       [FieldOffset( 0 )]
       float f;
       [FieldOffset( 0 )]
       IntPtr t;
    }

    class NDGETVAL
    {
      uint opt;
      NDVAL val;
     byte type;
    }
```